# Book about Entity System?

Tags: architecture, entity-system

I'm really interested about the capabilities of Entity System. I'm trying to search for a good book on this one, but failed.

I don't want to get lost on learning this paradigm so a book will be a big help. Can someone recommend a good book?

Also, is this language agnostic? Or are there languages that will have a hard time implementing this paradigm (eg. Objective-C)?

Thanks.

Comment: in case you missed these sites, though i daubt you did http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/ (there's a link section at the end) and http://t-machine.org/index.php/2007/09/03/entity-systems-are-the-future-of-mmog-development-part-1/ and the wiki. TBH, though, if there does exist a book specific to Entity Systems, it's extremely well concealed.

Comment: It's definitely not specific to any language. Obj-C is a fine choice.

Comment: I've already read about them. I need to re-read the one in cowboy though. Concealed...now that makes it more interesting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I learned about game entity systems through the book [Game Engine Architecture](http://www.gameenginebook.com/) by Jason Gregory. He discusses several implementations, ranging from class based to purely aggregate components, complete with examples. I highly recommend it, not just for that section, but for anybody who wants to know how to structure code for their game.

Edit: Just found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901251/component-based-game-engine-design) on Stack Overflow with tons of resources

Comment: this book looks great, can't wait to buy it and dive right into it

Comment: Best game engine book available, in my opinion.

Comment: Other than these references this whole component/entity thing is nothing more than a design pattern or two thrown togehter so that's why you're not finding any giant, canonical works of literature about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: [3D Game Architecture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/012229064X) Very well explained and with a full game engine as a "code snipped".