# Any recommended books/resources on component-based design?

Tags: unity, entity-component

I come from a background with heavy use of the classical object-oriented paradigm for software development.

The company I am a part of switched to Unity not too long ago, and we're all very excited to get started using it  However, one aspect that have sparked my interested, and which I think will become a very important part of our future development, is Unity's approach to component-based design with scripting; with less focus on typical hierarchical aspect.

**Question**

I was wondering if anyone could recommend any good books on this subject? I have had trouble finding any books or books with reliable reviews, and was wondering if anyone more experienced here had something to say on the issue?

Any other kind of resource would be excellent too, I'm just interested in getting to learn everything I can about it.

***This is not meant as a discussion about best books or resources on the topic, but simply a question regarding any resources that any of you find useful.***

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: If you look at [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site, they have a tag system, the [entity-system](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system) tag and the [component-based](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based) tags have a good number of questions and answers about component based design :) Good luck! I wish I worked at a place that was remotely close to using Unity. Also one where everyone is excited about something...

Comment: Books: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24276/book-about-entity-system
Other links: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12529/what-designs-are-there-for-a-component-based-entity-system-that-are-user-friendl

Comment: Here's a link that discusses entity/object and component-based systems, similar to Unity. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23533/interaction-between-engine-parts/23578#23578

Comment: Questions asking for a list of resources are not on topic for the site because resources can die over time (and nobody's going to maintain them), and it's really something that's better suited to search engines.